# Does groovy have an easy way to resolve this issue?

Tags: groovy

Say I have something like this:

```
String[] a = myFile.split('/\\\\')
```

The above line has this: "/users/data/hub/doc/filename.csv"

```
String b = "${a[0]}/${a[1]}/${a[2]}/${a[3]}"     //users/data/hub/doc
```

If I create a new folder "CES", then in the String b it needs to be reflect (i.e CES/users/data/hub/doc). I know that adding extra "${a[4]}" will solve my problem however I just want to know is there any other way to resolve this problem because every time manually making changes will not be work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming you have a path:

```
def myFile = '/users/data/hub/doc/filename.csv'
```

And you want to split it on `/` (or `\` if it's a Windows path)

Then you can do:

```
String[] a = myFile.split('[/\\\\]')
```

Then, to join them back together, you can just do:

```
String result = a.dropRight(1).join('/')
```

This drops the right hand element (the filename), and then joins the others together, separated by a `/`

Answer (score 0):

Simple replacement would also do:

```
String path = '/users/data/hub/doc/filename.csv'.replaceFirst( /(.+)\/[^\/]+/, '$1' )
assert path == '/users/data/hub/doc'
```